# Can one create a rule in iptables for google's servers only?

Tags: iptables

I want to allow gmail (and only gmail or other Google properties, not other IPs) to access my pop3 server.

Is there a way to setup iptables to allow all IPs controlled by Google through my firewall?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a list of the IPs owned by google.  That list will change over time, so you will need to maintain it, but the process for obtaining the list is at least reasonably clear.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en gives the process, and you can translate that into a one-liner like so:

```
dig +short TXT @8.8.8.8 _spf.google.com  | perl -ne 'print join "\n",m/'nclude:([^ ]*)/g' | xargs -n 1 dig +short TXT @8.8.8.8 | perl -ne 'print join "\n", m/ip[46]:([^ ]*)/g'
```

Now you need just a little more munging to turn that into firewall rules, and you'll have something you can run from cron to maintain your firewall as google's IPs occasionally change.  There's room for a bit of variation in how to do that though.  Do you manipulate iptables directly, or do you go via a more friendly firewall configuration tool? (e.g. I mostly use `ferm`).

Comment: iptables directly